# Votes on comments not being credited

Tags: support, comments

The other day a comment of mine had three helpful votes. These have not been credited in the helpful flags total in the profile. There was at least one other occurrence a month or two ago where one vote was not credited. Is this a stack bug or are helpful votes only selectively credited?

Comment: Do you mean that you had a comment with 3 upvotes?  You don't get reputation from comments.

Comment: You mean [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20459949/program-crashes-when-reading-a-long-text-file-exe-has-stopped-working#comment30571401_20459949)

Comment: @rene  Just curious...how'd you search by comments?

Comment: Visit the profile of the OP, clicked activity tab...@Andy

Comment: It's the helpful comments total that the post is about - nothing to do with reputation. Quite chuffed though about the high appraisal of my post!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A "Helpful Flag" means that you flagged a post for moderator review and your flag was deemed helpful by a moderator. Upvoting comments has nothing to do this process.

Answer (score 9):

You don't get reputation for comment upvotes.

Comment: The OP could go for the pundit badge ( Left 10 comments with score of 5 or more ) which the OP doesn't have yet.

Comment: did I mention reputation in the post? I meant helpful flags.

Comment: @suspectus You should have been more clear with that. Could we see some screeshots of the flags as you see them?

Comment: @suspectus Are you expecting that a vote on your comment increment your helpful flags count? The two are not related whatsoever.